# Using Apple's Automator using rsync - want to see the rsync progress times displayed

Tags: rsync, automator

Using Automator on OSX
Passing selected files/folders to rsync using a service. It is working and copies are succesful. Although want two things to happen and one question as to how to reference the "current" users desktop in the destination.

1. Want it to open terminal and visibly show the copy process with the --progress option that rsync offers. A GUI window would be nice but wanting simple for now.
2. Would like a simple "completed" message to be displayed somehow. Either in the terminal window or a GUI message.
3. Where the First.Last is used in the destination path, how can this be defined to simple use the current users desktop?

Below is what is working now but without the 3 things mentioned above.

```
for f in "$@"; do
/usr/bin/rsync --verbose --progress --times "$f" /Users/First.Last/Desktop/copy
echo "$f COMPLETED"
done
```

Thanks for any and all suggestions.